# find apollo cache item by __ref id

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to locate an apollo cache item by the id of the __ref it contains.
a snippet of my cache is available below:

```
WorkItem:b6b09053-75d2-4b16-a1e2-06c652892203:
id: "b6b09053-75d2-4b16-a1e2-06c652892203"
name: "accept_objective"
subject: {__ref: "Objective:7fdd9233-fb6d-487f-b6e6-0d2879168800"}
__typename: "WorkItem"
```

I only have the objective ID available on this page of the application. How can I find and discard the workItem with the subject.__ref of the objective id I have? I was currently trying the following but its not working.

```
cache.modify({
          id: cache.identify({
            __typename: 'User',
            id: id
          }),
          fields: {
            workItems(existing: Reference[], { readField }): Reference[] {
              //@ts-ignore
              const workItemId = existing.map(workItem => workItem.subject.id == objectiveId)
              //@ts-ignore
              return existing.filter((e: Reference) => readField('id', e !== workItemId));
            }
          }
        });
```

I am pretty new at manipulating the cache directly and any help would be greatly appreciated!